# Keras Callback instance has no attribute 'set_model'

Tags: python, callback, keras

I am trying to record the status of each epochs used in Keras using callback feature of keras. This is the sample code of callback class

```
class TimingCallback():
    def __init__(self):
        self.logs=[]
    def on_epoch_begin(epoch, logs={}):
        self.starttime=time()
    def on_epoch_end(epoch, logs={}):
        self.logs.append(time()-self.starttime)
```

This is my model fit.

```
cb = TimingCallback()
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, callbacks=[cb])
```

While executing i get the following error.

**Error:**

> AttributeError: TimingCallback instance has no attribute 'set_model'

Can anyone help me to figure out why exactly this is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`set_model` is a method defined in `keras.callbacks.Callback`. To write a custom callback, you'll have to subclass `keras.callbacks.Callback`. Otherwise, your callback will lack some necessary methods used by Keras internally.

Changing the first line into the following line should work.

```
class TimingCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
```